# C# api 2.0 POST always keeps pending instead of returning data

Tags: c#, api

I created a web api that get's called from an angular frontend. When I debug my Post call it works as expected, however when I return my 'newItem' object it keeps saying pending in the network XHR log. if I change my OK(newItem) to  a 204 status code it does work properly and it doesn't stay pending. Any one has any Idea what could cause this behaviour? Many thanks in advance.

My API code

```
using DWP.Services.Interfaces;
using DWP.ViewModels;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DWP.Api
{
    [Authorize()]
    [RoutePrefix("api/teamnewsviews")]
    public class TeamnewsViewsController : ApiController
    {

        ITeamnewsViewsService _teamnewsViewsService;

        public TeamnewsViewsController(ITeamnewsViewsService teamnewsViewsService)
        {
            this._teamnewsViewsService = teamnewsViewsService;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string teamnewsItemId)
        {
           TeamnewsViewsViewModel newsItem = new TeamnewsViewsViewModel();
           var teamNewsItem = _teamnewsViewsService.GetTeamnewsView(teamnewsItemId);

            newsItem.Id = teamNewsItem.Id;
            newsItem.TenantId = teamNewsItem.TenantId;
            newsItem.NewsItemId = teamNewsItem.NewsItemId;
            newsItem.ViewCount = teamNewsItem.ViewCount;

            return Ok(newsItem);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Increment")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(string teamnewsItemId)
        {
            if (teamnewsItemId == "")
            {
                return BadRequest("The newsitem Id is invalid");
            }

            var teamNewsItem = _teamnewsViewsService.GetTeamnewsView(teamnewsItemId);

            if (teamNewsItem == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            var newItem = _teamnewsViewsService.IncrementViewCount(teamNewsItem);



           // var updatedTeamnewsitem = _teamnewsViewsService.GetTeamnewsView(teamnewsItemId);

            return Ok(newItem);


        }

    }
}
```

My db service implementation:

```
using DWP.Data.Helpers.Interfaces;
using DWP.Data.Model;
using DWP.Services.Interfaces;
using System.Linq;

namespace DWP.Services
{
    public class TeamnewsViewsService : ITeamnewsViewsService
    {
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public TeamnewsViewsService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            this._unitOfWork = uow;
        }

        public TeamnewsView GetTeamnewsView(string teamnewsId)
        {
            TeamnewsView teamnewsViews =
                this._unitOfWork
                .GetRepository<TeamnewsView>()
                .GetAll()
                .Where(tnv => tnv.NewsItemId == teamnewsId).FirstOrDefault();

            return teamnewsViews;
        }

        public TeamnewsView IncrementViewCount(TeamnewsView teamnewsView)
        {
            teamnewsView.ViewCount =  teamnewsView.ViewCount + 1;
            this._unitOfWork.Commit();


            var newTeamNewsItem = GetTeamnewsView(teamnewsView.NewsItemId);

            return newTeamNewsItem;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it has a cericular reference error to another table. I fixed it by making a viewmodel as in the code below.

```
   TeamnewsViewsViewModel vm = new TeamnewsViewsViewModel();
        var newItem = _teamnewsViewsService.IncrementViewCount(teamNewsItem);
        vm.ViewCount = newItem.ViewCount;
```